# Set unknown variable / os.rename - Python

Tags: python, variables, rename

I am trying to rename files using python but i didn't find how to set an unknown variable

```
    import sys,os

    os.rename('picture(.+?).png', 'true.png');
```

I want the script to find "picture_1444.png" for example and rename it to "true.png", I know that in batch we use " * " to set an unknown variable and I want the equivalent of that " * " in python.

So I've tried this :

```
   import sys,os

   episode = creepy; 
   serie = pasta; 
   output = str(serie)+'_'+str(episode); 
   names = glob.glob('picture_[0-9]*.png') 
   if matching_names:
        os.rename(names[0], ''+output+'.png');
```

but i've got an error on

```
   names = glob.glob('picture_[0-9]*.png')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`os.rename()` does *not* expand wildcards. You could use the [`glob.glob()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob) to list matching filenames then move the first one found:

```
matching_names = glob.glob('picture_[0-9]*.png')
if matching_names:
    os.rename(matching_names[0], 'true.png')
```

Comment: I've tried this 
  `import sys,os
         episode = creepy;
                serie = pasta;
                output = str(serie)+'_'+str(episode);
                names = glob.glob('picture_[0-9]*.png')
  if matching_names:
  os.rename(names[0], ''+output+'.png')`
  
but i've got an error on names = glob.glob('picture_[0-9]*.png')

Comment: I don't know, it just shows me that it can't "read" that line... How can I check ?